# Quality Centre, TestSetFactory [PYTHON]

Tags: python, hp-quality-center

I have a problem with dumping testsets list from HP QC. I'm using TestSetFactory object and simple SQL query and I receive > object (I'd love to receive dictionary filled base dump. What is wrong with this code? If you have a questions about implementation some function, write.

```
 def create(self):
        self._report_connector.connect()
        self.qc_test_set_factory = self._report_connector._get_factory(self._path)
        test_sets = self.qc_test_set_factory.NewList("SELECT * FROM CYCLE ")
        if test_sets == None:
            print " no results"
        for test in test_sets:
            pprint.pprint(test)    #<---- it print me <COMOBject <unknow>>
            print len(test_sets)   #<---- it print me 1
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. What is the `create` function trying to do - ie: what is it creating?  Also, what do you expect the size of the list to be, is 1 incorrect?

Comment: Thanks for interest! Task of create function is creating dictionary, which contain records from quality centre database. It is impossible, that their length is 1. basically I want create XML with all records from db. _report_connector is dispatched TDConnector from HP API, qc_test_set_factory is TestSetFactory (I want use it to stretch records from db) and test_sets is dictionary which has stucture as like database's table.

Comment: It's not impossible that the length is 1. You've shown by printing len(test_sets) that it is 1. What is the result of `type(test_sets)`?

Comment: The result of type function is "<type 'instance'>

Comment: You should post your solution so others can avoid similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain about the accuracy of the rest of the code, but you do not pass a SQL query to the TestSetFactory.NewList method.  If you want everything, pass an empty string.

```
test_sets = self.qc_test_set_factory.NewList("")
```